# Subscribing to pipe containing TakeUntil fails

Tags: rxjs, grafana, rxjs6

I am trying to write a Grafana plugin using RxJS. 
Every logic to get my data stream to Grafana works and the complete pipeline works.

Now I need to stop the stream in case any options are changed.
I found in different blog posts and in the documentation 
the advice to use `takeUntil`.

Therefore, I created a observable emitting a event when I want to abort the stream. But any try to subscribe to the stream fails now, with

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

This problem exists only when takeUntil is introduced. This is especially weird since I use TypeScript and therefore the Return Type should be safe.

To debug the problem I pasted the example from the [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takelast.html)

```
/// RxJS v6+
import { interval, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit value every 1s
const source = interval(1000);
//after 5 seconds, emit value
const timer$ = timer(5000);
//when timer emits after 5s, complete source
const example = source.pipe(takeUntil(timer$));
//output: 0,1,2,3
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The problem persists. I checked my installed version of rxjs and yarn resolved it to 6.5.3. I checked the GitHub Issues of rxjs but didn't find any related issues.

I suppose the problem lies within my environment and conclusively I included all of my depedencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@grafana/toolkit": "next",
    "@grafana/ui": "latest",
    "@types/grafana": "github:CorpGlory/types-grafana.git",
    "@stomp/rx-stomp": "latest",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.25.0"
    "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"    
  }
```

Snippet of my own implementation

```
class LiveStreams {
 private streams;
 private stop$: Subject;

 constructor() {
   this.stop$ = new Subject<string>();
 }

 getStream(target): Observable<DataFrame[]> {
     const stop_id = this.stop$.pipe(takeWhile(id => id == target.streamId));
     stream = this.rxStomp.watch(target.streamName).pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    delete this.streams[target.streamId];
                }),
                map((message: IMessage) => {
                    let content = JSON.parse(message.body).content;
                    appendResponseToBufferedData(content, data);
                    return [data];
                }),
                throttleTime(target.throttleTime),
                takeUntil(stop_id)
            );
       this.streams[target.streamId] = stream;
   } 
}
```

Any clues on which parts of my environment to check would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more code.. I can't see your takeUntil anywhere...

Comment: Took the wrong example from the documentation. Updated with for more code for clarification.

Comment: What line throws the error? What you have seems fine.

Comment: `getStream(target): Observable<DataFrame[]>` not return anything

Comment: Any try to subscribe to the stream fails

That's true for the docs example as well, that fails in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a real answer, but I managed to circumvent to usage of TakeUntil for Grafana.

For anyone else coming here for Grafana: 
Grafana automatically unsubscribes if the requests do not match anymore. 
Therefore it is just necessary to remove the own cached version of the stream.

```
delete streams[streamId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach, it is not complete and not tested, but supposed to give you some inidication:

```
  private streams: Observable<any>[];
  stopTriggers: Subject<boolean>[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStream(123).subscribe(stream => {
      // console.log(stream);
    });
  }

   addStream(target) {
     this.stopTriggers[target.streamId] = new Subject<boolean>();
     const stream = of('something').pipe(
                // finalize(() => {
                //     delete this.streams[target.streamId];
                // }),
                // map((message: IMessage) => {
                //     let content = JSON.parse(message.body).content;
                //     appendResponseToBufferedData(content, data);
                //     return [data];
                // }),
                // throttleTime(target.throttleTime),
                takeUntil(this.stopTriggers[target.streamId])
            );
      this.streams[target.streamId] = stream;
   } 

   getStream(id): Observable<any> {
     return this.streams[id];
   }

   stopStream(id) {
     this.stopTriggers[id].next();
     this.stopTriggers[id].complete();
   }

   removeStream(id) {
     this.streams.splice(id,1);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your try!
The error persists. As I said, I shouldn't be about my specific code but probably about the environment. 
Otherwise the documentation example would have already worked I suppose.

It's a grafana datasoure plugin, not a complete Angular App. https://grafana.com/docs/plugins/developing/datasources/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. I don't know what is the reason for the error. I would like to have a small [StackBlitz](http://stackblitz.com) example to be able to debug your example because code is not so obvious.

My piece of advice to solve this issue is to move more to the reactive approach in this solution. You could create an observable with your options and use a `switchMap` operator to solve your case. I think it will be much more readable and maintainable from the developer perspective.

I don't know the requirements of your class. So, unfortunately, I cannot give a code example to you.

Good luck!

P.S. Please, post an updated if you already have solved this problem. I would like to take a look at the reason for the issue.

Comment: I suppose the problem lies within Grafana and not within RXJS.
Could be that grafana sends a stop trigger to early making the pipeline stop before anything gets out. 
I would close it, since I wasn't able to reproduce it on StackBlitz.
Still, thanks for your time!